# UIButton enable doesn't work

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a UIViewController with a single button and an activity indicator.
In the class for this VC `MainViewController.m` I do the following in `viewDidAppear`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _actLoadLoc.color = [UIColor blueColor];
    _startButton.enabled = NO;
    [_startButton setTitle:@"Fetching Location" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
}
```

Another method in my `MainViewController.m` is called `readyToGo` and is implemented as follows:

```
-(void) readyToGo
{

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0f];
    NSLog(@"Done sleeping");
    _startButton.enabled = YES;
    [_startButton setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _actLoadLoc.stopAnimating;
```

}

I have properties for both `UIButton`, `UIActivityIndicatorView` and a declaration of the `readyToGo` method in my `MainViewController.h` as follows:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *startButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *actLoadLoc;
-(void) readyToGo;
```

The `readyToGo` method is called from another class `abc.[h/m]` which imports `MainViewController.h`. The call happens after one of the functions in `abc.m` completes filling an array with calculated data.

The call works since `Done Sleeping` shows in the output, however the `startButton` is not enabled, its test does not change and the `actLoadLoc` does not stop animating... Any idea what's wrong with my code/method?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Is there any particular reason why your view controller only has `weak` references to the `UIButton` and the `UIActivityIndicatorView` views?

Comment: Not really, it was the default in Xcode 5 and I left it that way... Changing to `strong` doesn't fix the issue I think (see @Wain 's answer below), does it?

Comment: Weak is good, they are retained by their superview @ShaggyFrog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `readyToGo` on the wrong instance of the view controller. You have an instance which is displaying content on the screen and you are, in some way, creating a new one to call the method on. You need to get the existing one instead.

---

It's not ideal, but you should be able to get the controller with:

```
UINavigationController *n = (UINavigationController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
SDPPMainViewController *mvc = (SDPPMainViewController *)[n viewControllers][0];
```

(Will need to add some casts, and should probably break out to multiple lines)

Comment: What you say is correct, from abc.m, I do create a new instance of MainViewController... How can I get the existing one from abc.m? 

If the above is not possible, then is it possible to load/feed the button/activityindicator to the NEW instance? Thanks!

Comment: That depends on how the view controllers are associated. Something must own the one you want. What are the transitions between them?

Comment: abc.m is not a view. Just a helper class that calculates data that is needed by a `UITableViewCon` that is loaded when the user pushes the `startButton`. That's why I disable the button until abc.m tells my `MainViewController` that is is done calculating data and filling an array with the results...

Comment: So is main vc the root view controller of the app window (initial in a storyboard)?

Comment: There's a `Navigation Controller` before it but I didn't do any changes to it... So `NavigatioN Controller` --> `MainViewController` --> ...

Comment: Tried to get your update to work but could not...

        SDPPMainViewController * mvc = (SDPPMainViewController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController viewControllers][0];
    
    [mvc readyToGo];

ISSUE: Doesn't recognize viewControllers: No visible Interface for UIViewController declares the selector viewControllers...

Comment: That's where you need a cast to tell the compiler that the root vc is a nav controller.

Comment: Still trying. Will mark as an answer once I get it to work... Apologies but I am on the low intermediate side of the SDK...

Comment: Your update worked perfectly! Thanks a lot! Now I have to read about UIApplication and understand it! Thanks again @Wain!